# How to use Test Jars for spark in SBT

Tags: apache-spark, intellij-idea, sbt

I am creating Spark 2.0.1 project and want to use Spark test-jars in my SBT Project.

build.sbt:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.0"
val sparkVersion = "2.0.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % "compile",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion % "compile",
    "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.6" % "test",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % "test" classifier "tests",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion % "test" classifier "tests",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-catalyst" % sparkVersion % "test" classifier "tests"
)
```

My Test code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.test.SharedSQLContext

class LoaderTest extends org.apache.spark.sql.QueryTest with SharedSQLContext {
  import testImplicits._

    test("function current_date") {
      val df1 = Seq((1, 2), (3, 1)).toDF("a", "b")
      // Rest of test code and assertion using checkAnswer method
    }
}
```

But when i try to run test using:

```
sbt clean test
```

It get following errors:

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /tstprg/test/target/scala-2.11/test-classes...
[error] bad symbolic reference to org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.PredicateHelper encountered in class file 'PlanTest.class'.
[error] Cannot access type PredicateHelper in package org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions. The current classpath may be
[error] missing a definition for org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.PredicateHelper, or PlanTest.class may have been compiled against a version that's
[error] incompatible with the one found on the current classpath.
[error] /tstprg/test/src/test/scala/facts/LoaderTest.scala:7: illegal inheritance;
[error]  self-type facts.LoaderTest does not conform to org.apache.spark.sql.QueryTest's selftype org.apache.spark.sql.QueryTest
[error]     class LoaderTest extends org.apache.spark.sql.QueryTest with SharedSQLContext {
[error]                                                   ^
[error] /tstprg/test/src/test/scala/facts/LoaderTest.scala:7: illegal inheritance;
[error]  self-type facts.LoaderTest does not conform to org.apache.spark.sql.test.SharedSQLContext's selftype org.apache.spark.sql.test.SharedSQLContext
[error]     class LoaderTest extends org.apache.spark.sql.QueryTest with SharedSQLContext {
[error]                                                                  ^
[error] bad symbolic reference to org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder encountered in class file 'SQLImplicits.class'.
[error] Cannot access type Encoder in package org.apache.spark.sql. The current classpath may be
[error] missing a definition for org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder, or SQLImplicits.class may have been compiled against a version that's
[error] incompatible with the one found on the current classpath.
[error] /tstprg/test/src/test/scala/facts/LoaderTest.scala:11: bad symbolic reference to org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical encountered in class file 'SQLTestUtils.class'.
[error] Cannot access term logical in package org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans. The current classpath may be
[error] missing a definition for org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical, or SQLTestUtils.class may have been compiled against a version that's
[error] incompatible with the one found on the current classpath.
[error]           val df1 = Seq((1, 2), (3, 1)).toDF("a", "b")
[error]                                         ^
[error] 5 errors found
[error] (test:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

Can anybody who tried using test-jars of spark to unit test using SBT help what i am missing?

Note: This test works fine when I run through IntelliJ IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the scope as mentioned below

````
version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.11"
val sparkVersion = "2.3.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % Provided,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % Test classifier "tests",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % Test classifier "test-sources",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion % Provided,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion % Test classifier "tests",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion % Test classifier "test-sources",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-catalyst" % sparkVersion % Test classifier "tests",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-catalyst" % sparkVersion % Test classifier "test-sources",
  "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging" % "3.9.0",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.4" % "test",
  "org.typelevel" %% "cats-core" % "1.1.0",
  "org.typelevel" %% "cats-effect" % "1.0.0-RC2",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion % Provided,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql-kafka-0-10" % sparkVersion % Provided exclude ("net.jpountz.lz4", "lz4"),
  "com.pusher" % "pusher-java-client" % "1.8.0") ```
````

Answer (score -1):

Try changing scope of your dependencies marked as test like below

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.0"
val sparkVersion = "2.0.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion,
    "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.6",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion ,
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion,
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-catalyst" % sparkVersion
)
```

or adding "compile".

Comment: Thanks. But, I tried putting scope 'test' and 'test->test', but still not able to get it running.

Comment: Added detailed answer

Comment: It does not work as we need test jars of spark-core,spark-sql and spark-catalyst.